# app icon not show in facebook profile

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to show my app icon in facebook profile when i post something on my wall. 
I have done with facebook developers account and have completed the create new app section where i have submitted my app icon.
        But when i post on my wall I can see only the string not the icon.

```
    here is my snippet of code.

    -(IBAction)btnPost:(id)sender
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"myPB", @"name",
                                       @"http://www.my-t3.com/", @"link",strFbmsg, @"message",
                                       nil];
        [appdelegate._facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    }
```

Comment: just pass another object in the dictionary with name picture and put your image icon in that. It will work.. i did it.

Comment: sory it not working, i want to show image on tab but there is a blank space . image not show

Answer (score 0):

Add a new object in your dictionary with a http link to your image and insert it with key "picture".

Example:

```
     [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     nil];
```